# iframe within an iframe [IE]

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, cross-domain

Got a small issue where my inner iframe that is ran within a parent iframe is not displaying its content in IE ( works on all other browsers ). The only way to show the iframe content if the iframe src URL is ssl compliant.

Is this a known issue or scenario with IE and is blocking the child iframe because of a security issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IE will block all content (including iframes) with an http:// URL if the page containing the content is https://